# How to refer to enum constants in c# xml docs

Tags: c#, documentation, enums, xml-documentation

I want to document the default value of an enum typed field:

```
/// <summary>
/// The default value is <see cref="Orientation.Horizontal" />.
/// </summary>
public Orientation BoxOrientation;
```

The compiler warns that it couldn't resolve the reference.  Prefixing F: or M: silences the compiler, but E: also does, so I'm unsure what prefix is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The prefixes `F`, `M` and `E` are all valid and probably the reason that the compiler warning disappears.

You should however use the `F` that refers to fields. For more information on how Visual Studio generates documentation identifiers see:

[Processing the XML File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should need the prefix - probably you need to add a "using" to the namespace where the `Orientation` type is defined.

Comment: Late to the party, but this is probably the correct answer. Also note, that if you have naming collisions, you need to add one (or more) level(s) of the namespace: say you have a class `NamespaceX.A` with property `MyEnum` of type enum `NamespaceX.Enums.MyEnum` (same name) and the enum has an enumeration value of `One`. IN the class `NamespaceX.A` you reference with `<see cref="MyEnum" />` the property `NamespaceX.A.MyEnum`. If you want to reference the enum instead, use `<see cref="Enums.MyEnum" />` or if you want to reference the enumeration value use `<see cref="Enums.MyEnum.One" />`